# Node.js, Express: How can I handle res.send values with the client

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm a newbie in node.js, and I'm also using express.

I build a simple web application to upload files to a server, and save them, when they are okay. That works fine, but now I want to inform the client about the current state( is it uploaded or did it not work, because of the large size from the file).

I know that I should use `res.send()`, but I want to display it on the same page( with all elements on "upload.html"), where the client uploaded the file. I guess, I have to using client sided javascript to work with the sended information, but how do I communicate with server side javascript and client side javascript? Or do I not need to use client sided javascript?

(I would like to combine it later with HTML, so I can design the answer from the server with CSS.)

server.js:

```js
var     express = require('express'),
        fileUpload = require('express-fileupload'),
        fs      = require('fs'), 
        obSizeOf  = require('object-sizeof'),
        app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(fileUpload());

app.get("/upload.html", function(req, res){
        res.sendfile(__dirname + "/" +"upload.html"); 
})

app.post('/upload.html', function(req, res) {
 if(obSizeOf(req.files.sampleFile) > 10000000)
        {       
                res.send("The size of the not-uploaded file is to large! Please use a file with a maximal size of 10MB");
                return;
        }
        else
        {
                var sampleFile;       
                if (req.files.sampleFile.name == "") {
                        res.send('No files were uploaded.');
                        return;
                }
                else
                {
                        sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
                        var typ = sampleFile.mimetype.split("/");
                        console.log(typ[0]);
                        if(fs.existsSync("public/upload/image/"+typ[0]+"/"+sampleFile.name))
                        { 
                                res.send("A File with the same name already exists! Please rename it!");
                                return;                        
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                sampleFile.mv('public/upload/'+typ[0]+'/'+sampleFile.name , function(err) {
                                  if (err){
                                  res.send('File NOT UPLOADED!');
                                        }
                                        else { console.log("Mieeep!"); res.send(typ[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+typ[0].slice(1) +' data uploaded!');
                                        }
                                });
                        }
                }
        }
});
app.listen("8000");
```

/upload.html:

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <form ref='uploadForm' 
   id='uploadForm' 
   action='/upload.html' 
   method='post' 
   encType="multipart/form-data">
   Upload File
   </br>
    <input type="file" name="sampleFile" />
   </br>
    <input type='submit' value='Upload!' />
   </br>
   <p id="serverInformation"></p> <!--Placeholder for information from the server-->
   Only images
  </form>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You ask for real time information sending, you should use [web socket](http://socket.io/).

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is socket programming. Using node js you can do that easily.

just see [this link](http://socket.io/docs/) for more on socket and node js.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AJAX  and check the error status. there

...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#uploadForm").submit(function() {

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
    url: "/upload.html",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    complete: function(xhr, statusText){
       alert(xhr.status+" : "+ statusText); 
    }
  })
 })
})
 </script>
```